# What determines quality of midi playback in Mathematica?

Tags: sound

I'm using *Mathematica* 10, and ocassionally when I import a midi file and play it, the sound is very disappointing!

- the sound volume seems to vary (sometimes normal, sometimes very low)
- some instruments have particularly poor sound quality

I've tested the same files in [KMPplayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) without any issues.

Has anyone else seen these sorts of quality issues? How can I improve or adjust the sound quality of midi sounds in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you adjusting the `SampleRate` ?

Comment: @Sektor Nope...I did nothing else. I just import a midi file and click the "play" button.And when I export midi right after import,the sound quality becomes poor,too.  The code is like this: Sound[{SoundNote[...],SoundNote[...],...}]

Comment: @QhelDIV I believe Mathematica plays MIDI using Java.  This means that you're hearing Java's default MIDI quality.